Changing the data source of QgsVectorLayer with PyQGIS
I am trying to update the data sources of all the layers of a project. I am going from a SQLite source to a PostgreSQL db source. I can't delete and re-add the layers because there is a large number of references to layers in the themes and so forth.
It is possible to right-click on every layer and change it this way. How do you duplicate that process with PyQGIS? QgsRasterLayer has a setDataProvider() method but there isn't something similar for QgsVectorLayer that I can find.

https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#ae83df6c7934ff7d69d2e94052af9340a Python API: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.setDataSource
